# Dynamic Expression Parameter

Tags: c#, linq, expression

How can i make dynamic expression parameter ?

i was try

```
public List<Station> GetStationsByTimeAndState(StationState stationState, int? categoryId = null, int? provinceId = null, int? districtId = null)
{
    List<Station> stations;
    Expression<Func<Station, bool>> exp = p => p.StationState == stationState;

if(categoryId==null){
exp+= p.CategoryId==categoryId;//or exp.Add()//exp.Update()
}

.....

return stations = stationDal.GetList(exp);
    }
```

The GetList method calls the Where query that belongs to Linq in itself.

What I want to do is dynamically constructing and sending the expression inside the Where query.

Comment: Why do you think operator `+=` is defined for `Expression`?

Comment: You may want to consider using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a [Linq Expression Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) for your example this would look like this:

```cs
// Parameter: p
Expression<Func<Station, bool>> exp;

var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Station));

// p == stationState
var equalsStationState = Expression.Equal(
     Expression.Property(stateParameterExpression, nameof(Station.StationState))
    Expression.Constant(stationState));

if (categoryId != null)
{
    // p.CategoryId == categoryId
    var equalsCategory = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(stateParameterExpression, nameof(Station.CategoryId)),
        Expression.Constant(categoryId));

    // (p == stationState) && (p.CategoryId == categoryId)
    var andExpression = Expression.AndAlso(equalsStationState, equalsCategory);

    // p => (p == stationState) && (p.CategoryId == categoryId)
    exp = predicate = Expression.Lambda(
        andExpression,
        stateParameterExpression);
}
```

The code above is not complete, but you can get an idea on how it works.

As an alternative you could conditionally chain `Where` methods, which would be much simpler:

```cs
IEnumerable<StationList> stations = allStations
    .Where(s => s.StationState == stationState);

if (categoryId != null)
{
    stations = stations.Where(s => s.CategoryId == category)
}

return stations;
```